# Trying to understand the difference between "modernNeo ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL" and "modernNeo ALL=(ALL) ALL" in the sudoers file

Tags: permissions, sudo

In the `sudoers` file, you can have either of the following lines

```
modernNeo ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
modernNeo ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

I looked at the following answers on here to understand this

- [Sudoers file, enable NOPASSWD for user, all commands](https://askubuntu.com/questions/334318/sudoers-file-enable-nopasswd-for-user-all-commands/340669#340669)
- [What is the difference between `root ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL` and `root ALL=(ALL) ALL`?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/546219/what-is-the-difference-between-root-all-allall-all-and-root-all-all-all/546228#546228)
- [Effect of (ALL:ALL) in sudoers?](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1918842)
- [What does "ALL ALL=(ALL) ALL" mean in sudoers?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/201866)

#### Question 1

If I understand correctly from those above answers:

- `(ALL:ALL)` means that you can run the command as any user and any group
- `(ALL)` means that you can run the command as any user but your group remains the same [it remains your own group] - regardless of the user you become when you use `sudo` with `ALL` for the third entry?

#### Question 2

But with `(ALL:ALL)`

- If you can run it as any group, how does sudo decide what group you run the command as if you don't specify it on the commandline using `-g`?
- does it first try to run it as your own group and then go through a list of all the groups on your machine before finding the group that allows you to run the command?
- Where does it get the list of groups from and what is the order of the groups on that list?
- Or does it just revert to using `root` for user and/or group when your preference for what user and/or group you want to become isn't specified? If that is the case, why do `(ALL:ALL)` when you can do `(root:root)` ?

#### Question 3

Furthermore, in [this Ubuntu Forums post](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1918842&p=11657481#post11657481), with regards to the following lines

```
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

They say that

> Users in the admin group may become root. Users in the sudo group can only use the sudo command. For instance, they could not `sudo su`

> `(ALL:ALL)` refers to `(user:group)` that `sudo` will use. It can be specified with `-u` and `-g` when you run `sudo`. If you don't specify anything it will run as `root:root`, which is the default. That's how most end up using it anyway.

That confuses me; they are stating that if you can take on any group when running a command, then you are unable to become root?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

A line like:

```
smith ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

will allow the user smith to use sudo to run at any computer (first ALL), as any user (the second ALL, the one inside parentheses) any command (the last ALL). This command will be allowed by sudo:

```
smith@site ~ $ sudo -u root -g root bash
```

But this won't:

```
smith@site ~ $ sudo -u root -g smith bash
```

as the permissions for ANY group have not been declared.

This, however:

```
smith ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

will allow this command to be executed (assuming user `tom` and group `sawyer` exist):

```
smith@site ~ $ sudo -u tom -g sawyer bash
tom@site ~ $ id
uid=1023(tom) gid=1087(sawyer) groups=1047(tom),1092(sawyer)
```

Having said that:

## Q1

> (ALL:ALL) means that you can run the command as any user and any group

Yes

> (ALL) means that you can run the command as any user …

Yes

> … but your group remains the same [it remains your own group]

No, the only group allowed is `root`.

## Q2

> how does sudo decide what group you run the command as if you don't specify it on the commandline using `-g`?

It defaults to `root`.

> does it first try to run it as your own group and then go through a list of all the groups on your machine before finding the group that allows you to run the command?

No.

> Where does it get the list of groups from and what is the order of the groups on that list?

There is no list to use. 
As stated above, it simply falls to default `root`
when `user:ALL` is used,
or to the named group if `user:group` is used.

Simple rules, simple actions.

> Or does it just revert to using `root` for user and/or group when your preference for what user and/or group you want to become isn't specified?

Yes.

> If that is the case, why do (ALL:ALL) when you can do (root:root) ?

Because with `(ALL:ALL)` you can do:

```
sudo -u tom -g sawyer id
```

But with `(root:root)` you can only do:

```
sudo -u root -g root id
```

and nothing else (user- and group-wise).

## Q3

For these lines:

> > 

```
%admin  ALL=(ALL)     ALL
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

> Users in the admin group may become root.

Yes, users in the `admin` group (%) could become ANY user (including root) (because of the `(ALL)`) but only the `root` group.

> > Users in the sudo group can only use the sudo command.

That is incorrect. The users in the `sudo` group (%) could execute any command (the last `ALL`).

Users in the `sudo` group (%) could become any user (the `(ALL:)` part)  **and** any group (the `(:ALL)` part) **AND** may execute any command (the last `ALL`) (not only sudo, which is specifically incorrect).

> > For instance, they could not `sudo su`

No, they could do `sudo su` or `sudo ls`
or `sudo anycommand`.

> > `(ALL:ALL)` refers to `(user:group)` that `sudo` will use. 
> > It can be specified with `-u` and `-g` when you run `sudo`.

They are correct here. The command `sudo -u tom -g sawyer ls` is correct and valid.

> > If you don't specify anything it will run as `root:root`,
> > which is the default.

And are correct here as well. The command `sudo ls` will be executed with `root:root` credentials (i.e., powers / privileges).

> > That's how most end up using it anyway.

Correct, the most used `sudo` command doesn't specify either a user or group.
So, it is the *"most used, anyway"* (default `root:root`).

> That confuses me... they are stating that if you can take on any group when running a command, …

Yes, they state that with `(ALL:ALL)` the `sudo` command could take any user or group.

And:

> … then you are unable to become root?

No, that interpretation is incorrect.

- with `(ALL:ALL) ALL` sudo is allowed to become any user with any group to execute any command. Even root.
- with `(ALL) ALL` sudo lose the ability to set the group, but could still set the user and run any command (`sudo su -` is allowed).

Comment: Excellent explanation - some confusion about the Question 3 is because the comments in the `/etc/sudoers` file - `# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges` for `%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL` and `# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command` for `%sudo ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL` - I have the same confusion at - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/670761/etc-sudoers-clarification-about-all-vs-allall-for-groups

Comment: The last sentence of your answer seems to be saying that the OP is misreading [the linked Ubuntu Forums post](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1918842&p=11657481#post11657481). But that post ***is*** wrong; you say so yourself. IMHO, this is confusing.

Comment: @Scott (1) Yes, this is confusing. (2) The [linked Ubuntu Forums post](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1918842&p=11657481#post11657481) involves three users: BLAK111 (asking) Dangertux (asserting that users in sudo group could only execute the sudo command) and Lars Noodén (clearing the errors in the last post). All those comments have been joined in one post by the OP here, that makes answering even more challenging. So, to start, not all of them are saying the same thing, some have correct statements and errors at the same time. (3) There is no **one post** correct or not. (Cont)

Comment: Modified the description at the end, I hope that will make things clear. @Scott