# /etc/sudoers - clarification about "all" vs "all:all" for groups

Tags: permissions, sudo, users, group, privileges

About configuration(s) for the `/etc/sudoers` file with `visudo` I have read the following tutorials (among others):

- [How To Edit the Sudoers File](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-edit-the-sudoers-file)
- [Linux visudo command](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/visudo.htm)

A very important part is the following structure:

- `user hostname=(runas-user:runas-group) command`

I understand the following about *users*:

```
root ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
hope ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

What is not clear for me is about the `%groups`. In the `/etc/sudoers` file are shown the `%admin` and `%sudo` groups as follow:

```
# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL
# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

About `(ALL)` vs `(ALL:ALL)`

1. When the former would be mandatory over the latter and viceversa?
2. What type of commands should work with the former and latter respectively

So, it is not clear for me (even with the available comments for each one), therefore if I want create and a new group (i,e: `developers`) I don't know if should be declared `(ALL)` or `(ALL:ALL)`.

Comment: cross posted https://askubuntu.com/questions/1366076/etc-sudoers-clarification-about-all-vs-allall-for-groups

Answer (score 5):

The 'run-as-specification' is coupled with the `-u` and `-g` options of `sudo`.

1. With `(ALL)`, you are allowed to run the subsequent commands as any user. The syntax for that will be `sudo -u <user> command`.
2. With `(:ALL)` you are allowed to run the subsequent commands as any group. The syntax for that will be `sudo -g <group> command`.
3. With `(ALL:ALL)`, you are allowed to run the subsequent commands as any user and/or as any group. Note that this configuration does not force the use of a user and group, so you can do:

- `sudo -u <user> command`
- `sudo -g <group> command`
- `sudo -u <user> -g <group> command`

See the ['Runas_Spec'](https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.9.7/sudoers.man.html#Runas_Spec) section of the sudoers manual for more details, and some examples.

Comment: There's no difference in security between `ALL` and `ALL:ALL` unless `command` is restricted to a command that cares about its primary group when running as root. Both allow running with arbitrary permissions since you can rebound on the root user. The reason to choose between a wildcard and a specific user/group has nothing to do with personal workstation vs restricted environment, it's about what the rule is for.

Comment: @Haxiel (1) I have never `(:ALL)` for groups, interesting (2) about _"The (ALL:ALL) option offers maximum flexibility, but limited security"_ - what is the problem with security?

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' - "The reason to choose between a wildcard and a specific user/group has nothing to do with personal workstation vs restricted environment, it's about what the rule is for" can you pls post your answer and expanding the explanation for that? - the point of my question is know when use `(ALL)` vs "(ALL:ALL)"

Comment: @ManuelJordan I seem to have gone off on a tangent there; sorry about that. I'll remove that section for now and will update it after a bit more research.