# Help me understand the permission syntax in sudoers file

Tags: sudo

Based on the file itself:

> Next comes the main part: which users can run what software on which
> machines (the sudoers file can be shared between multiple systems).
> Syntax:
>
> ```
>   user    MACHINE=COMMANDS
> ```

OK for example we have this:

```
john.doe ALL=(ALL:ALL) /sbin/ifup, /sbin/ifdown
```

which means john.doe is given permission to issue the ifup and ifdown commands using sudo.
What I don't understand is the part in parenthesis. I just know that the first one is user and the second is group. But what is this for while we already have specified users in the first of line?
Thank You

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trying to understand the difference between "modernNeo ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL" and "modernNeo ALL=(ALL) ALL" in the sudoers file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/490835/trying-to-understand-the-difference-between-modernneo-all-allall-all-and-m)

Comment: `john.doe` is the user who's allowed to run `sudo` here, and `ALL:ALL` refers to the users that `john.doe` can run these commands as. (`sudo`'s not just for running as root  - you can run commands as other users too)

Comment: It's real simple according to the man page that then goes in to walls of text explaining how it works :/  Is [this](https://toroid.org/sudoers-syntax) explanation enough? I think a whole book could be dedicated to the topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Breaking down your example:

1. john.doe
2. ALL=
3. (ALL:ALL)
4. /sbin/ifup, /sbin/ifdown

(1) The user john.doe can (2) regardless of the machine name (3) pretend to be any (ALL) user-id, or belong to any (:ALL) group for the purposes of running (4) these commands.  So, for instance, john.doe run the `/sbin/ifup` command as any user he wishes:

```
$ sudo -u vahid2015 /sbin/ifdown eth0
```

and you'd get the blame!

Generally you don't need the (ALL:ALL) part, the default is root and that is the most common case.  If a use should run a command as, let's say, and operator use (operator) for the uid or (:operator) for the gid.

It's good to specify the machine names if possible, however the use of `ALL=` permits a common `sudoers` file to be maintained across a managed set of machines.

Comment: sample time you run sudo as non root is `sudo -u apache rm /var/www/html/someplace/*` you then need `john.doe (apache)  rm /var/www/html/someplace/*`

Comment: Good example, but shouldn't it be `john.doe (apache)  rm`?

Comment: well `/bin/rm` and you may want to restrict apache's files john.doe is allowed to delete.

Comment: Did you miss machine name?  john.doe ALL =(apache) ....

Comment: By the way when I make a file as root user I can't modify it under another user in direct admin so I have to sudo as another user/group